# Display row and count of referenced row in SQL select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables. as follows

### Table: Category

```
categoryID  categoryName
----------  -------------
    1         Fruit
    2         Country
    3         Car
```

### Table: Items

```
 ItemID    CategoryID   ItemName
 -------   ----------   ----------
    1          1         Apple
    2          1         Mango
    3          1         Banana
    4          2         USA
    5          2         Japan
    6          3         Honda
    7          3         Toyota
```

I need a select query which will give me the categories, along with the count of items under each category. like this:

```
categoryID  categoryName    ItemCount
----------  -------------   ----------
    1         Fruit             3
    2         Country           2
    3         Car               2
```

How can I achieve this in a SQL query? I need a single query, not a procedure with variables :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select c.categoryID, c.categoryName, count(*) as ItemCount
FROM category c
inner join items i on i.categoryId = c.categoryId
GROUP BY c.categoryID, c.categoryName
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT c.categoryID,  c.categoryName, count(*) as 'ItemCount' 
FROM Category c, Items i 
WHERE c.categoryID = i.categoryID 
GROUP BY c.categoryID,  c.categoryName;
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8da4e/2)

Hope this helps